# Img src url with variables

Tags: javascript, html, image, variables, src

I would like to load an image with the page load using javascript and html.  Here was my original code that worked perfectly in IE11 and Firefox on Windows 10 but not in IE11 on Windows7.  Is it the syntax/quotes that it doesn't like?

```
var1 = "someURl";
var2 = "someEndingToURl";
var mainImgsrc = var1 + 'some_text' + var2;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.getElementById('IMG1').src= mainImgsrc

<img id="IMG1" src="" width="1000px" height="700px" name="mymap" align="middle" alt="Map" ;/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the basic method...

```
<body onload="IMG1.src= mainImgsrc;">
```

The onload event is supported by all popular engines including Trident.

Comment: This worked perfect.  I was overthinking it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jotter & @user4723924, this is a bad practice. See my answer. You should be wrapping all your JS in a `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` listener.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here. Do you have a link to the site you are using? Perhaps the lack of `var` in front of `var1` and `var2` means you are unintentionally overwriting a global variable? You can fix that by adding `var` and moving those inside of your `DOMContentLoaded` listener (to avoid them being implicit globals):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var var1 = "https://makelin.us/";
  var var2 = "/70";
  var mainImgsrc = var1 + '100' + var2;

  document.getElementById('IMG1').src = mainImgsrc;
});
```

```html
<img id="IMG1" src="" width="100" height="70" name="mymap" align="middle" alt="Map" ;/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your DOM is fully loaded before trying to change an image SRC.
Have you tried to console.log() your document.getElementById ? 
BTW, your code is not properly written, you miss }); after your SRC assignment.